# Getting aspect-ratio of pgf plot axis right

Tags: pgfplots

I'm using tikz for creating a few plots. I using the `axis` environment to create the plot. Using the `height` and `width` options, I can set the size of the plots. I want an aspect-ratio of 2, so I set `width=\linewidth` and `height=0.5\linewidth`. It turns out that the aspect ratio is not 2, but approximately 2.36 instead. Any idea how to fix this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
        \begin{axis}[
            width=\linewidth,
            height=0.5\linewidth,
            xmin=0, xmax=2,
            ymin=0, ymax=1,
            ticks=none,
            red
        ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding `scale only axis`, without it the `width` and `height` includes some space (45pt) for axis labels, as described in the manual.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for you answer, it works like a charm

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thanks for sharing. Actually, the answer suggested in your post, works for me. However, to my understanding, the question is different. In my case, the problem is the extra space (45pt, as mentioned above) that is included in the `width` and `height`. I don't think that is the problem with the question you are referring to (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: To (relatively) new users it seems a bit strange, but "duplicates" here refer to *answers* and not *questions*. So if an *answer* in another question (regardless of the question itself) answers *your* question (and thus would yield in the "same" answer) this would be a duplicate. Thus, you are right, the question (itself) is a bit different than yours.

Comment: (It would be nice if you would consider upvoting the answer that helped you in the duplicate question.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, I did not know this! And sure, I will upvote it :)